# Echarts shows wrong data on box and whisker plot

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm trying to make a box and whisker plot with Echarts framework, and I want to show this array on the first box of plot:

```
disorderValuesArray =  [0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0.13 ,0.13 ,0.13 ,0.13 ,0.13 ,0.13 ,0.13 ,0.13 ,0.13 ,0.13 ,0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.13 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.38 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.63 , 0.63 , 0.63 , 0.63 , 0.63 , 0.63 , 0.63 , 0.63 , 0.63 , 0.63 , 0.63 , 0.63 , 0.75 , 0.75 , 0.75 , 0.75 , 0.75 , 0.75 , 0.75 , 0.75 , 0.75 , 0.75 , 0.88 , 0.88 , 0.88 , 0.88 , 0.88 , 0.88 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1.13 , 1.13 , 1.13 , 1.13 , 1.13 , 1.13 , 1.13 , 1.13 , 1.13 , 1.25 , 1.25 , 1.25 , 1.25 , 1.25 , 1.38 , 1.38 , 1.38 , 1.38 , 1.38 , 1.5 , 1.5 , 1.5 , 1.5 , 1.5 , 1.5 , 1.57 , 1.63 , 1.75 , 1.75 , 1.75 , 1.75 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2.38 , 2.5 , 2.5 , 2.5 , 2.5 , 2.63];
```

the problem is that maximum value is 1.57 in the tooltip and top whisker ends in location 1.57 while my maximum in the disorderValuesArray is 2.63, but the median line position is correct it is 0.25.
[disorderValuesArray box plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NblDL.png)
so I tried with this array:

```
testArray = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7];
```

in this case the plot is correct and it shows correct maximum in the tooltip and maximum position is correct too.
[testArray box plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQmL8.png)
and here is my code:

```
function makeData() {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        var cate = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 276; j++) {
            cate.push(Math.random() * 4);
        }
        cate.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b;});
        data.push(cate);
    }
    return data;
}
var data0 = makeData();
var data1 = makeData();
var data2 = makeData();
data0[0] = disorderValuesArray;
option = {
    title: {
        text: 'Multiple Categories',
        left: 'center'
    },
    dataset: [{
        source: data0
    }, {
        source: data1
    }, {
        source: data2
    }, {
        fromDatasetIndex: 0,
        transform: { type: 'boxplot' }
    }, {
        fromDatasetIndex: 1,
        transform: { type: 'boxplot' }
    }, {
        fromDatasetIndex: 2,
        transform: { type: 'boxplot' }
    }],
    legend: {
        top: '10%'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        axisPointer: {
            type: 'shadow'
        }
    },
    grid: {
        left: '10%',
        top: '20%',
        right: '10%',
        bottom: '15%'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        boundaryGap: true,
        nameGap: 30,
        splitArea: {
            show: true
        },
        splitLine: {
            show: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        name: 'Value',
        min: 0,
        max: 7,
        splitArea: {
            show: false
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'category0',
        type: 'boxplot',
        datasetIndex: 3
    }, {
        name: 'category1',
        type: 'boxplot',
        datasetIndex: 4
    }, {
        name: 'category2',
        type: 'boxplot',
        datasetIndex: 5
    }]
};
var chartDom = document.getElementById('disorder-box-plot');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
myChart.setOption(option);
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum value is not wrong it is calculated by this formula:
max = Q3 + (1.5 * IRQ)
and IRQ is (Q3 - Q1). The rest of values higher than this calculated max are outliers. Also the min value is calculated by: Q3 - (1.5 * IRQ) and the rest of values lower than calculated min is outliers.